# "Встать" и "становиться": корень один, а значения разные

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Подумалось: а как вышло, что однокоренные слова начали (стали!) обозначать разные понятия? "Стать" (кем-то, чем-то) и "встать на ноги". А в просторечии приставку В- отбрасывают и говорят "стань тут".

Answer (score -1):

Разные виды глагола.
*Встать* - глагол совершенного вида
*Становиться* - глагол несовершенного вида.

Answer (score -1):

Я не вижу тут разных понятий. Бифонема СТ означает устойчивое состояние. 
Стать кем-то означает, что человек занял устойчивое состояние в своей профессии. 
Встал на ноги - занял устойчивое вертикальное положение относительно пола.